# Select method is not called using LinQ query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I want to enable LinQ query syntax over my classes. I think query syntax is translated to method syntax, for example:

```
var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
        where p.Id == "1000"
        select p
```

is translated to:

```
var query = new Class1<Product>().Where(p => p.Id == "1000").Select(p => p);
```

Then I have implemented my `Class1` as:

```
public class Class1<T>
{
    public Class1<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public Class1<T> Select<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> expression)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And I have tested it with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
                where p.Id == "1000"
                select p;
}
```

Then I have noticed that `Select` method is not called, however if I remove `where` clausule from LinQ `Select` is called:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
                // where p.Id == "1000" -> commenting that Select method is called
                select p;
}
```

Someone knows why?

Here a fiddle where you can test it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JgxKG9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Someone knows why?

Yes, because that's what the language specification says to do. The query expression translation is all in section 7.16.2 of the C# 5 specification.

Section 7.16.2.5 explains why your initial example is incorrect - `Select` won't be called:

> A query expression of the form
>
> ```
> from x in e select v
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> ( e ) . Select ( x => v )
> ```
>
> **except when *v* is the identifier `x`, the translation is simply**
>
> ```
> ( e )
> ```
>
> For example
>
> ```
> from c in customers.Where(c => c.City == “London”)
> select c
> ```
>
> is simply translated into
>
> ```
> customers.Where(c => c.City == “London”)
> ```

However, that isn't the case for *degenerate query expressions* which are covered in 7.16.2.3 - which explains what happens when you remove your `where` clause:

> A query expression of the form
>
> ```
> from x in e select x
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> ( e ) . Select ( x => x )
> ```
>
> The example
>
> ```
> from c in customers
> select c
> ```
>
> Is translated into
>
> ```
> customers.Select(c => c)
> ```
>
> A *degenerate query expression* is one that trivially selects the elements of the source. A later phase of the translation removes degenerate queries introduced by other translation steps by replacing them with their source. It is important however to ensure that the result of a query expression is never the source object itself, as that would reveal the type and identity of the source to the client of the query. Therefore this step protects degenerate queries written directly in source code by explicitly calling Select on the source. It is then up to the implementers of `Select` and other query operators to ensure that these methods never return the source object itself.

Comment: nice to see the specifications part, you found very quickly @Jon!!

Comment: @JonSkeet do you know the specs off memory? That was quick enough! :-)

Comment: it's not Jon who searches for C# specs. They search for Jon. :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I knew exactly what to look for, and where the specs are on my system :)

Comment: @JonSkeet wow, so you have them on your pc, great, can you point to the link to have specs offline downloaded?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Sure - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the specs come with Visual Studio... on a default install, you can find them on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\VC#\Specifications\1033`. Not sure if they changed on VS 2017

Comment: In my case, they are on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\3082 and the are translated to my language (spanish). I didn't know.

Comment: @JavierRos yep, the 3082 is the locale id (1033 for english, 3082 for Spanish (Spain) - others [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms912047(v=winembedded.10).aspx) )

Comment: Nice to see section **7.16.3 Query expressions pattern**, just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is little incorrect, the following query :

```
var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
        where p.Id == "1000"
        select p
```

will translate to :

```
var query = new Class1<Product>().Where(p => p.Id == "1000");
```

and when you are removing the `where` part:

```
var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
            select p;
```

now it will be translated to something like:

```
var query = new Class1<Product>().Select(p=>p);
```

Comment: And why is called if I remove the `where` clausule?

Comment: @Jon has explained better than me referencing with  specifications :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I think there's a mistake here: "and when you are removing the **select** part:" should be **where**

Comment: I'm upvoting because you were fast, even if you didn't reference specs

Comment: i knew the answer so couldn't wait out of cusriosity :D yeah specs support more the answer in this kind of questions where user ask Why this works and that not :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that the translation from query syntax to method syntax optimizes the call to `Select` away if it states an *identity projection*.

Since `p => p` would project everything to itself and the `Where` clause already added an abstraction layer between the source sequence and the result, this call is no longer necessary.

So

```
var query = from p in new Class1<Product>()
            where p.Id == "1000"
            select p;
```

is only translated to

```
var query = new Class1<Product>().Where(p => p.Id == "1000");
```

But I admit that I only guess that and am still searching for the relevant specification part.
*Update: Jon was faster*